# Set edit text position to the right of the parent,which is being added dynamically on a button click

Tags: android

I am adding a table row each time the ADD button is clicked.
The row contains one edit text only.
But I want position of edit text to be right of parent every time.
It is taking leftmost position by default now.

```
t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      TableRow row1 = new TableRow(create_form.this);
      EditText edttxt1 = new EditText(create_form.this);
      row1.addView(edttxt1);
      t1.addView(row1);
   }
});
```

How to set position right to parent each time it is added dynamically on button click?

Answer (score 1):

Set Gravity to `TableRow`:

```
      row1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Haha I was testing with these properties, you became first.. thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

When you define the table in the xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
```

In this way, every table row is aligned right.